# How to replace 2 or more special characters or underscores appearing together in a string Python

Tags: python, string, str-replace

I have the following string:

```py
'___5weeks_rollingAverage_8hours'
'___5weeks__rolling=*%Average_8hours'
'___5weeks_rollingAverage_8hours__'
'___5weeks_rollingAverage_8hours'
```

I wish to remove `_` if it appears more than once anywhere in the string. So the above should translate to:

```py
5weeks_rollingAverage_8hours
```

tvm

Comment: what about line 2 it has another punctuations and two underscore converts to one ?

Comment: yes. if it has other punctuations appearing `together` then it should also be removed e.g. `'___5weeks_rollingAverage_..8hours,,'` will translate to `5weeks_rollingAverage_8hours`

Comment: Also second one, has 2 underscores between `5weeks` and `rolling`, so according to your explanation it should be removed.

Comment: yes... any non alphanumeric character that appears more than once together should be removed e.g. `__, ,% , $£, .; ,` these all should be removed

Comment: But in this case the second one will result in `5weeksrollingAverage_8hours`, not `5weeks_rollingAverage_8hours`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use regular expression as you said for non alphanumeric we can use [^a-zA-Z0-9] so the code is something like this:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}')
t = '___5weeks_rollingAverage___8h**ou&%rs'

result = regex.sub("",t)
print(result)
```

**Output:** 5weeks_rollingAverage8hours

Comment: nice and clean and easy to understand. thanks so much :D

Answer (score 0):

using regex

```
import re

test_str = ("___5weeks_rollingAverage_8hours", "___5weeks__rolling=*%Average_8hours",
            "___5weeks_rollingAverage_8hours__", "___5weeks_rollingAverage_8hours")

regex = re.compile(r"[!\"#$%&'()*+,-.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~]{2,}")
for item in test_str:
    item = regex.sub('', item)
    print(item)
```

output

```
5weeks_rollingAverage_8hours
5weeksrollingAverage_8hours
5weeks_rollingAverage_8hours
5weeks_rollingAverage_8hours
```